# Iterate OpenCl Kernels

Tags: c++, c, opencl, gpu

What is the most efficient way to iterate through a set of kernels in OpenCl. So pseudo code is

```
for i : max {
    <kernel 1>
    <kernel 2>
    <kernel 3>
}
```

Do I just have to iterate through this function creating a long CommandQueue, or can I load the kernels dynamically once one has finished? (P.s the kernels all have to share some global data).

Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use in-order Command Queue & push kernel to it in desirable order:

```
// Creating in-order command queue (default case).
cl_command_queue queue = clCreateCommandQueue(...);

// Just for test
std::vector<cl_kernel> kernels;
const int num_kernels = 12;

for(int i=0; i<num_kernels; i++){
    kernels.push_back(clCreateKernel(...));
}

for(cl_kernel &kernel : kernels){
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel,...);
}

/* Kernels execution tasks are issued on Device all at once.
 * Execution order is same to order of enqueue, as Queue is in-order.*/
clFlush(queue);
```

Comment: As a note you can use events to chain your kernels together into dependency lists using this style as well.  That way you can use an out of order queue and still push the whole list all at once.